# How to allocate memory for an array of pointers to a char in c

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've working on a program in c and got stuck with allocating memory for an array of pointers to char, I will need to sort this array in the future. Array should store chars in it and then I want to sort these chars in alphabetical order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct
{
    char collection[50]; 
} data_col;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    data_col * array [10] = malloc(sizeof(data_col));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &array[i]->group);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code has so many errors that it is impossible to guess what you want to achieve. Please describe what you want. At least provide code that can be compiled. -- At least describe why you need the pointer array.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: @Alessa Why do you have decided that you need an array of pointers instead of an array of objects of the structure type?

Comment: Using an array of pointers kind of makes sense if you'll be sorting it; you can swap two elements by just swapping their pointers instead of swapping 50 bytes of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate the memory for your 10 pointers by simply writing this:

```
data_col * array[10];
```

If you put this at the top level of your program, it is a global variable and you can use it any time during your program, and the pointers are all initialized to null pointers for you.

If you put it in a function, then the memory will be deallocated/freed when the function returns.  The pointers will start in an uninitialized/undefined state.

Note that you still need to initialize each of these 10 pointers before you can use them for anything.  You might choose to use `malloc` to allocate the space for the individual `data_col` objects, or you could make an array of `data_col` objects and have your pointers pointing into that array.  However, your question wasn't about that; your question is simply about how to allocate memory for the *array of pointers*, and the code I showed above succeeds in allocating that memory for you.